# Discriminator based multi-tenancy with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

There is a shared database that has a discriminator field "*customer_id*" in each collection. That is an approach that was taken for multi-tenancy support.

**What would be the recommended approaches on how to implement support of the discriminator field in the latest Spring Data MongoDB?**

The most straightforward way I can see at this point is to set "*customer_id*" in the ThreadLocal per each request (The data is exposed via REST API) and then just pass to each Spring Data method

```
findByXxxAndCustomerId(x, ThreadLocal.getCustomerId())
```

Comment: "Discriminator field" is supposed to store the type of object that the document is. See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#changing-the-discriminator-key. For your customer id you can store it in thread-local storage if you like.